# How to select all nodes of a certain type connected via an Edge?

Tags: orientdb

I am quite new to OrientDB, I have a Node labeled Resource, and i have other nodes labeled User and Administrator connected to it. I know I can Select all the Users who are "HasAccessTo" the Resource, like this:

```
SELECT in("HasAccessTo") FROM Resource
```

But how do I write the Query if I want to Select only those who are labeled as User and not Administrator?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer:

```
 SELECT FROM (
   SELECT expand(in("HasAccessTo")) FROM Resource   
 ) WHERE @class = "User"
```

Short answer:

```
SELECT in("HasAccessTo")[@class = "User"] FROM Resource
```

or (expanded)

```
SELECT expand(in("HasAccessTo")[@class = "User"]) FROM Resource
```